# Different memory dumps generated by being internal/external to a process

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, memory

I have been playing around lately with memory dumping and stumbled upon something that I didn't fully understand.

If I have a process and dump its memory contents by using VirtualQueryEx & ReadProcessMemory to grab the data and dump it to a file everything is ok. Meanwhile, I have tried doing the same thing by being internal to the process and doing VirtualQuery and just dumping the contents of the pointers it returns.
I was able to do this by proxying one of the DLLs of the process I am testing on.
Now, the problem is that these two memory dumps are different ( missing areas from the dump created from inside the process )
Could somebody enlighten me as to why this is happening ?
Windows XP SP3 + Visual Studio 2008
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to dump? Speaking about all the memory pages that are allocated by the process then I think that you can get different values because of the internal process state that is (in general) unique per time. Also, if you are dumping process's memory outside the process then the dumper's code is not in the dumping process address space while if you are dumping process from inside the process, the process now includes the dumper's code. So, it may be useful to dump only certain number of pages belongs to process application or DLL's.

Comment: I'm trying to dump everything except the code; and yes i know that the process now includes the dumpers code, i have taken that to account; the internal and external dumps are in sync yet, regions are missing from the internal one

Comment: Can you try to lock memory with VirtualLock() before dumping? And could you get some info about what kind of pages are missed?

Comment: My assumption is that Thread Stack pages are missing but I really can't tell; also, I wouldn't do VirtualLock() as this is for a game and it may have ... consequences; to run within it i am hooking a DLL function; it's like i cannot 'see' everything from a hooked-inside thread.

Comment: Well, try to walk through every user-mode page (4K) and for each page try to get it's first byte. If the page is not allocated by the process, you should get an AV-exception so skip to the next page. For every present page call VirtualQuery and then dump it if needed. It's an advice that can give us some information...

Comment: That would be a painfully slow way to go through the memory; the point is, would there be a reason for the memory i see from inside the process to be different from the memory i see from outside the process content wise ? ignoring the presence of the dumper and considering perfect sync.

Comment: Theoretically, the only difference you have to seen is the dumper's code. But I can't say that it's true on windows. You will need to make some experiments (for ex. with AV, as I pointed).

Comment: I checked right now, some of the Thread Stack regions are missing.

Comment: Interesting. Can you check witch threads belongs this regions? I suspect that windows can create auxiliary threads when you are dumping from outside the process. May be it's CSRSS related things... Can't say exactly, but the problem is really interesting.

Comment: Thread Stack regions from various threads are missing including main thread. They are also flagged as PAGE_GUARD which is curious that this flag hasn't been raised by either both dumpers - internal and external

Comment: Well, concerning the threads, it's stack growth implementing via the PAGE_GUARD technique so first access to that pages with a `push` command cause the system to allocate the new page. So initially stack pages marked with PAGE_GUARD reserved but they are not committed.